# Auto reply for cancelled account in Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

An employee of us left, and I want to cancel his Google Apps account (paid version).

Is there a way, where after I cancel his account, I can add an auto reply for his alias in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make employeegone@example.com an nickname (alias) of another user. For that user, you enabled Canned Responses lab (`Settings > Labs > Canned Responses`) and create the auto-response message you want.

You then create a filter for emails sent to employeegone@example.com and have it send the Canned Response you have created. You may also want to archive, mark-as-read or some other handling of the message at the same time.